# Loop arcsin possible answers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, robotics

I am currently taking a robotic course in my study . There is a lab that we require to find inverse kinematics for our robots and in order to do that, there will be many arcsin and arccos needed to find the all the theta(s)

For example,

```
theta1 = arcsin(2/3)    <--- This will give two answers
theta2 = arcsin(theta1/2)     <--- This will give 2 answers with 2 different theta1
theta3 = arcsin(theta1/theta2) <--- This too
```

So my question is , how do I loop to find all the multiple solutions for those dependent equations ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the input and the expected output?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. There are infinite number of solution to the equation 2/3 = sin(y) so it makes no sense "to get two answers".

Comment: Since sin is a cyclic function, there is actually an infinite amount of solutions, x = x0 + 2k*pi for any integer k. arcsin just returns the solution with 0 <= x < 2*pi.

Comment: @Chemistree Additionally, there are the solutions `x=(2k+1)*pi - x0`. And arcsin usually returns the solution -pi/2<x<pi/2.

Comment: @chtz oh yeah of course